# Is there a way to use SQLiteDatabase with Room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I need to be able to perform a some operations that would be easily done with `SQLiteDatabase` but I'm using `Room`. Is there a way for me to get an instance of a `SQLiteDatabase` object for that `Room` database? I've already tried the `RoomDatabase` object but the operations available are pretty limited compared to `SQLiteDatabase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RoomDatabase` has [`getOpenHelper()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase?hl=en#getopenhelper), which returns a `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper`. As with `SQLiteOpenHelper`, `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` offers `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritebleDatabase()` methods. Those return [a `SupportSQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase).

`SupportSQLiteDatabase` is not identical to `SQLiteDatabase`, but it is close, and it is supported by more SQLite implementations than just the framework SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily get an SQLiteDatabase BUT NOT via Room.

e.g. assuming the Database Name passed to the databaseBuilder is defined as a constant DATABASE_NAME in the TheDatabase class then you can use. Also that `a_context` is a context *(e.g. by using `this` in an activity)*

```
 SQLiteDatabase sqlitedb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(a_context.getDatabasePath(TheDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Obviously, you need to be careful using both Room and the above (probably ensuring that the each issues a close before the other opens).